# Underline on TextView only underlines first line of text

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I need to underline a part of text in a TextView which has multiple lines. I have added paint flag to underline a text:

```
textView.text = resources!!.getString(R.string.a_string)
textView.paintFlags = textView.paintFlags or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG
```

However, it only underlines text on the first line and not the second and further. Furthermore, it just randomly does not work on some TextView's and works on others. Can someone explain if there are any special considerations, special cases where this works and where it does not?

Here is my TextView definition (ConstraintLayout):

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
      android:text="Some text taht goes to more than one line."
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/some_id"
      app:strokeColor="@color/black"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is stupid, but. **The underline on the second line was not visible due to the absence of bottom padding.** 
I added `android:paddingBottom="8dp"` and the underline became visible. I am not sure why I have to add it in the first place.